# UISearch record from sqlite database in ios

Tags: ios, sqlite

My question is UISearchDisplay controller using search record from sqlite database. and my query is UISearch bar search record from sqlite database properly display mytableview and my query is particular row select and pass different data in second view controller so i am passing data to index beyond bound error.. so any help me

```
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "ZpaleoViewController.h"

@interface SearchViewController ()

@end

@implementation SearchViewController
@synthesize strSearch,tblview,searchResult;

       - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];
           SWRevealViewController *revealViewController =  self.revealViewController;
          if ( revealViewController )
            {
            [self.slide6 setTarget: self.revealViewController];
            [self.slide6 setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )]
            [self.view   addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
           }

              appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication       sharedApplication].delegate;
         databse = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:appdelegate.appDBPath];

         [arrname removeAllObjects];
         [arrPaleo removeAllObjects];
         [searchResult removeAllObjects];

         arrname = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         arrPaleo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         searchResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

         [self searchRecord];

           }




        -(void)searchRecord{


           path =    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                        NSUserDomainMask, YES);
           docsPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
           dbpath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PaleoData.sqlite"];

          databse = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbpath];
          [databse setLogsErrors:TRUE];

          [databse open];
          NSString *selectQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select *  from ZFOOD"];

        FMResultSet *resultQuary = [databse executeQuery:selectQuery];


         while ([resultQuary next]) {


              NSString *z_cateory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [resultQuary stringForColumn:@"ZNAME"]];


             [arrname addObject:z_cateory];


             }
           [databse close];

          }

          - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
      {


                  NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate   predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];
                 searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [arrname filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];



          }

       -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
             [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope: [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]   objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];


       return YES;
      }

       - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     {

       return 1;
     }

          - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
              {

              if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)   {
             return [searchResult count];

             } else {
            return [arrname count];
              }


             }
               - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView          cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
           {



           static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
               if (cell == nil) {
              cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
             }


                if (tableView ==   self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
           {

              cell.textLabel.text = [searchResult   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

               cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
               cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"No.png"]];
             [cell.accessoryView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];


              }
              else
             {
              cell.textLabel.text = [arrname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
             cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
             cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"Yes_check.png"]];
             [cell.accessoryView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];
            }

       cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:99.0/255    green:170.0/255 blue:229.0/255 alpha:1.0];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
       cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:15];

          return cell;
         }

            - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
         {
         [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:NO];
         searchResult = nil;
         [tblview reloadData];

           }


           - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView     didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {

            [databse open];
             NSString *selectQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select ZPALEO     from ZFOOD where ZNAME = '%@'",[searchResult       objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

                 FMResultSet *resultQuary = [databse  executeQuery:selectQuery];
   // [arrPaleo removeAllObjects];
          while ([resultQuary next]) {


             NSString *z_paleo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",     [resultQuary stringForColumn:@"ZPALEO"]];

              [arrPaleo addObject:z_paleo];

              }

                [databse close];

                   ZpaleoViewController *objZpalieo = [self.storyboard        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"paleo"];

               NSString *objstr1 = [arrPaleo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
               objZpalieo.strpaleo = objstr1;
               [self.navigationController pushViewController:objZpalieo     animated:YES];

               }
          @end
```

Comment: your coding is fine , but you are pass the wrong index

Comment: where i am pass wrong index